# I am trying to create a calculator using react hooks. I was trying to get the current number and send it to the displayInput

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason, it doesn't show the input on the first click. It shows the first input on the second click. What am i doing wrong? Here is a snip of the code below.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Calculator() {
  const [displayInput, setDisplayInput] = useState('')
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState('')
  const [previusNumber, setPreviusNumber] = useState('')

  function handleNumber(e){
    setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + e.target.value)
    setDisplayInput(currentNumber)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{displayInput}</p>
      </div>
      <button value = {1} onClick = {handleNumber}>1</button>
      <button value = {2} onClick = {handleNumber}>2</button>
      <button value = {3} onClick = {handleNumber}>3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Calculator;
```

Comment: Can you make the text smaller? Please remove `#` from the beginning of first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because setState is `asynchronous`, so when you call `setDisplayInput(currentNumber)` in the first time  `currentNumber` still is initialState `''`. So you can update `setDisplayInput` as `setCurrentNumber`:

```
setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + e.target.value)
setDisplayInput(currentNumber + e.target.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for bug=> setState is asynchronous

```
const [displayInput, setDisplayInput] = useState('')
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState('')
  function handleNumber(e){
    setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + e.target.value)
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    setDisplayInput(currentNumber)
  } , [currentNumber])
```

OR

```
const [displayInput, setDisplayInput] = useState('')
  function handleNumber(e){
    setDisplayInput(displayInput + e.target.value)
  }
```

OR

```
 function handleNumber(e){
        setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + e.target.value)
        setDisplayInput(currentNumber + e.target.value)
    }
```